# Python mathematical expression evaluation

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was trying to solve a random problem, I used a relation that I made, when I've come to implement it in python it give me different results than the one that I calculated, so I tried to change.

**the thing is I don't get how does python see each one!!?**

- those two expressions here give different results sometimes:

  - `((column+1)//2) * ((row+1)//2)`
  - `= (column+1)//2 * (row+1)//2`
- Here's an example:

```
rows, columns = 4, 4

for row in range(2, rows+1):
    for column in range(1, columns+1):
        print('*'*15)
        result = ((column+1)//2) * ((row+1)//2)
        f_result = (column+1)//2 * (row+1)//2

        print('>> normal expression:', (column+1)//2, (row+1)//2)
        print('>> second expression:', ((column+1)//2), ((row+1)//2))
        print('>>               row:', row)
        print('>>            column:', column)
        print('>>           Results:', result, f_result)
    print()
```

- The last two entries in the results:

```
***************
>> normal expression: 2 2
>> second expression: 2 2
>>               row: 4
>>            column: 3
>>           Results: 4 5
***************
>> normal expression: 2 2
>> second expression: 2 2
>>               row: 4
>>            column: 4
>>           Results: 4 5
```

Comment: Yes, and that's normal when using integer division. If you don't want to use integer division, use `/`, not `//`.

Comment: but i can't understand what is happening!!

Comment: i get it now, the answer down below helped me

Comment: A better title would help make the question's answer useful to other people. Right now, someone seeing this title won't know that its answer will help them, even if they really do have the same problem.

Comment: ... a title that more effectively ties the question to your specific technical problem might be something like: "Why does 2 * 5 // 2 evaluate to 5 instead of 4?"

Comment: Also, provide output as copied/pasted text, not screenshots. See [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122) -- the rationale therein applies to output, not just code. I've edited to that end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand operator precedence first
[Check out this link](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/precedence-associativity)

Now for the expression

```
((col+1)//2) * ((row+1)//2) = (col+1)//2 * (row+1)//2
```

```
((col+1)//2) * ((row+1)//2) = ((4+1)//2) * ((4+1)//2)
                            = (5//2)*(5//2)
                            = 2 * 2
                            = 4
```

```
(col+1)//2 * (row+1)//2 = (4+1)//2 * (4+1)//2
                        = 5//2 * 5//2
                        = 2 * 5//2
                        = 10//2 (as * has higher precedence over //)
                        = 5
```